# TableLayout only appears when keyboard is showing

Tags: android, keyboard, android-tablelayout

In my Android application I am showing a chessboard (size is variable) with a TableLayout. The user can put in the width and height of the chessboard by a Dialog. When the user clicks on OK of the dialog the chessboard is updating to that format. But the weird thing is: when the keyboard is showing when clicking OK the TableLayout is perfectly showing, but when clicking OK when the keyboard is not showing, the TableLayout is not appearing. I will show the problem in pictures:

This is the AlertDialog.Builder without showing the keyboard

[image: This is the AlertDialog.Builder without showing the keyboard]

The TableLayout is not showing in this case

[image: The TableLayout is not showing in this case]

This is the AlertDialog.Builder with showing the keyboard

[image: This is the AlertDialog.Builder with showing the keyboard]

The TableLayout is showing perfectly now

[image: The TableLayout is showing perfectly now]

This is the function that is called when the user clicks on OK, so it updates the chessboard:

```
private void setupChessBoard(){
    tableLayout.removeAllViews();

    String[][] solution = new Algorithm(dimensionsDialog.getHeight(), dimensionsDialog.getWidth(), dimensionsDialog.getNumberOfQueens(), dimensionsDialog.getNumberOfBishops()).getSolution();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < dimensionsDialog.getHeight(); i ++){
        tableLayout.addView(new TableRowChess(this, dimensionsDialog.getWidth(), i, solution));
    }
}
```

This is the custom TableRow class:

```
public class TableRowChess extends TableRow {

private Context context;

private int numberOfColumns;
private int rowNumber;

private String[][] solution;

public TableRowChess(Context context, int numberOfColumns, int rowNumber, String[][] solution) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;
    this.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    this.rowNumber = rowNumber;
    this.solution = solution;

    initializeTableRow();
    initializeTextViews();
}


private void initializeTableRow(){
    this.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) numberOfColumns));
}

private void initializeTextViews(){
    TableRow.LayoutParams  params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i ++){
        SquareTextView tv = new SquareTextView(context);

        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setBackgroundResource(getCorrectBackground(i));
        tv.setHeight(tv.getLayoutParams().width);
        tv.setText(solution[rowNumber][i]);
        tv.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        this.addView(tv);
    }
}

private int getCorrectBackground(int columnNumber){
    if((rowNumber % 2) == 0){
        if((columnNumber % 2) == 0){
            return R.drawable.square_white;
        } else {
            return R.drawable.square_brown;
        }
    } else {
        if((columnNumber % 2) == 0){
            return R.drawable.square_brown;
        } else {
            return R.drawable.square_white;
        }
    }
}



}
```

I do not understand why is perfectly works when the keyboard is showing and why it does not work when the keyboard is hidden. I think it should not matter at all?

I hope someone can help me !

Comment: Try calling `invalidate()` on the `tableLayout` after adding the rows.

Comment: @MikeM. I already tried that, but it didn't work. I also tried the invalidate function on the RelativeLayout of the TableLayout, but also that does not work.